# How to scroll up and navigations bar while scrolling up and need to display while scrolling down

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

I need my Navigation bar to be scroll up and down while tableview is scrolling up and down.

Answer (score 0):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let defaultOffset = view.safeAreaInsets.top
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y + defaultOffset
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: min(0, -offset))
    }
```

It should work and I got this problem once, so this code helped me...Might it works for you too..